# Why a Trained Pybrain network yield different results even with an input use for training

Tags: python, neural-network, pybrain

I have trained a neural network using pybrain. But when i test my network using the same input as the one used for training, i get complete different result. Here is my code

```
from pybrain.structure import FeedForwardNetwork
from pybrain.structure import LinearLayer, SigmoidLayer
from pybrain.structure import FullConnection
import numpy as np
from pybrain.datasets import SupervisedDataSet
from pybrain.supervised import BackpropTrainer
from pybrain.tools.xml.networkreader import NetworkReader
from pybrain.tools.xml.networkwriter import NetworkWriter
from pybrain.utilities import percentError

n = FeedForwardNetwork()

inLayer = LinearLayer(2)
hiddenLayer = SigmoidLayer(3)
outLayer = LinearLayer(1)

n.addInputModule(inLayer)
n.addModule(hiddenLayer)
n.addOutputModule(outLayer)

in_to_hidden = FullConnection(inLayer, hiddenLayer)
hidden_to_out = FullConnection(hiddenLayer, outLayer)

n.addConnection(in_to_hidden)
n.addConnection(hidden_to_out)
n.sortModules()

X = np.array(([3,5], [5,1], [10,2]),dtype=float)
Y = np.array(([75], [82], [93]),dtype=float)
X/=np.amax(X, axis=0)
Y/=100

print(n.activate([ 1, 2]))
print(in_to_hidden.params)
ds = SupervisedDataSet(2,1)
for i in range(len(X)):
  ds.addSample(X[i],Y[i])

trainer=BackpropTrainer(n,ds, learningrate=0.5, momentum=0.05,verbose=True)
trainer.trainUntilConvergence(ds)
trainer.testOnData(ds, verbose=True)
```

Now when i want to test on an input using the code
`print("Testing",n.activate([3,5]))`
i get `('Testing', array([ 1.17809308]))` . I should have had around`0.75` for this input `n.activate([3,5])`. So i dont understand why this strange result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this is just one aspect of model validation that you will always have to undertake. The network generally seeks to minimise its error against all of the training data, but it will not get each result exactly. You could probably improve prediction accuracy by running more epochs with more hidden neurons. However, doing so would eventually lead to over-fitting through excessive flexibility. It's a bit of a balancing act.

As an analogy, take regression. In the linear case below, the model does not match any of the training (blue) data, but generally captures the trend for blue and red (external test) data. Using the linear equation would always give me the wrong answer for all data but it's a decent approximator. Then say that I fit a polynomial trendline to the data. Now it has a lot more flexibility, hitting all of the blue points but the error on the testing  data has increased.

[image: regression]

Once you have your network built, you need to rerun all of your data back through it. You can then validate on [absolute average deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_absolute_deviation), [MSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error), [MASE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_scaled_error) etc. in addition to things like k-fold cross validation. Your tolerance of error is based on your application: in engineering, I might always need to be within 5% error, and anything that exceeds that threshold (which would occur in the second graph) could have fatal consequences. In language processing, I might be able to tolerate one or two real mess-ups and try catch them another way if the majority of predictions are very close, so I'd possibly take the second graph.

Playing with your learning rate and momentum might help converge on a better solution.

EDIT: Based on comments

The comment "should have been able to recognise it" implies to me something different than the basis of the neural network. There is not even a vague concept of memory in the network, it simply uses the training data to develop a convoluted set of rules to try and minimise its error against all data points. Once the network is trained, it has no recollection of any of the training data, it's just left with a spaghetti of multiplication steps it will perform on input data. So no matter how good your network is, you will never be able to reverse-map your training inputs to exactly the right answer.

The idea of "convergence" cannot be taken to mean that you have a good network. The network might just have found a [local minima](http://mnemstudio.org/ai/nn/images/minima1.gif) in error and given up learning. That is why you **must** always validate your models. If you are not happy with the result of the validation, you can try improve the model by:
- Simply re-running it again. The random initialisation of the network might now avoid the local minima 
- Changing the number of neurons. This loosens or tightens the flexibility of the model 
- Change the learning rate and momentum 
- Change the learning rule e.g. swapping from Levenberg-Marquardt to Bayesian Regularisation

Comment: my question is why does give a complete different result, though my network have been trained until it converged? it should have had a value close to the actual one. i have to point out that the value i used for testing is a value i used for training. so my network should have been able to recognize it.

Comment: @user3841581 That is what I tried to illustrate with the regression graph. You can think of the linear model as your trained network. You can see that the line intersects none of the training data e.g. asking for an answer to a training example will give back a different result than what you expect. I cannot say whether 1.178 - 0.75 is a big discrepancy, it depends on your data (if it ranges from 1 to 1mil, the error is tiny). Also, how many example data do you train with in your actual model? If it's just 3 points, then you'll never have a great model.

Comment: i get your point,  we need more training examples. but is my model not suppose to get a good result for an example used for its training?

Comment: @user3841581 hopefully the edit makes it a bit clearer. You hope to get a good answer for the training data, but unfortunately it is in no way guaranteed :)

Comment: thank you; i changed the momentum to 0.5 and i have a better solution. i now have 0.72270291 for that example which is much more close to 0.75. Thank you

Comment: @user3841581 Great, glad it helped! Despite all the advancement in neural networks, there are only vague rules on what those values should be. In essence it's just to take a reasonable guess and move from there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't seen anything strange with the result. Just because you have a training instance with input `[3,5]` and output `[0.75]` it does not mean that the network should always produce the same output.  The model does not simply *memorize* training instances.

Comment: i got it now. I thought the model should have save the example it used for training